# Woocommerce checkout field maxlength, make input number field only (postcode)

Tags: functions, jquery, woocommerce-offtopic

I've been struggling with this for a few days now. What i want to do, it to limit the Postcode/zip fields to 4 numbers. So, to add a **maxlength** and a **type="number"** to those fields.

Things i've tried so far:

1 - (functions.php)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['postcode']['maxlength'] = 4;    
    return $fields;
}
```

2 - (functions.php) a jQuery way

```
add_action("wp_footer", "cod_set_max_length");

function cod_set_max_length(){

    ?>
    <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("#postcode").attr('maxlength','4');

    });

    </script>

<?php
```

Answer (score 2):

By the time `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter is run, the arrays for billing and shipping have already been created.

You can see that here: 
https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#101

If you want to effect the default fields, use this hook.

```
function wpse215677_checkout_fields ( $fields ) {
    $fields['postcode']['maxlength'] = 4;
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'wpse215677_checkout_fields');
```

If you want to adjust just the default billing fields:

```
function wpse215677_checkout_fields ( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_postcode']['maxlength'] = 4;
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wpse215677_checkout_fields');
```

Otherwise you just need to edit your array declaration:

`$fields['billing_postcode']['maxlength'] = 4;`

Answer (score 1):

You may add these functions in the functions.php of your theme:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields2( $fields ) {
$fields['shipping_postcode']['maxlength'] = 5;    
return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields2' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_postcode']['maxlength'] = 5;    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

Comment: Explanation of your code would be appreciated. Use comments to explain what your code is doing.